# Android change color of error validation text field

Tags: java, android, xml, validation, colors

If you take a look at the picture you can see the error text AND the text field go purple when I use setError() on the text field. I would like to make this RED like its supposed to be, does anyone know how to change this?

[Purple text field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv8mE.png)

RegisterActivity

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "RegisterActivity";

    @InjectView(R.id.nameWrapper) TextInputLayout _nameWrapper;
    @InjectView(R.id.input_name) EditText _nameText;
    @InjectView(R.id.input_email) EditText _emailText;
    @InjectView(R.id.input_password) EditText _passwordText;
    @InjectView(R.id.fragment_login_password_visibility) ImageView _passwordToggle;
    @InjectView(R.id.fragment_login_confirm_password_visibility) ImageView _confirmPasswordToggle;
    @InjectView(R.id.input_confirmPassword) EditText _confirmPasswordText;
    @InjectView(R.id.btn_signup) Button _signupButton;
    @InjectView(R.id.link_login) TextView _loginLink;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
        //_passwordToggle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //_confirmPasswordToggle.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        _signupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signup();
            }
        });

        _loginLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Finish the registration screen and return to the Login activity
                finish();
            }
        });

        _passwordText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                //_passwordToggle.setVisibility(s.length() > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                //_passwordToggle.setVisibility(s.length() > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }
        });
        _passwordToggle.setOnTouchListener(mPasswordVisibleTouchListener);

        _confirmPasswordText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                //_passwordToggle.setVisibility(s.length() > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                //_confirmPasswordToggle.setVisibility(s.length() > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }
        });
        _confirmPasswordToggle.setOnTouchListener(mConfirmPasswordVisibleTouchListener);
    }

    private View.OnTouchListener mPasswordVisibleTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final boolean isOutsideView = event.getX() < 0 ||
                    event.getX() > v.getWidth() ||
                    event.getY() < 0 ||
                    event.getY() > v.getHeight();

            // change input type will reset cursor position, so we want to save it
            final int cursor = _passwordText.getSelectionStart();

            if (isOutsideView || MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction())
                _passwordText.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            else
                _passwordText.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);

            _passwordText.setSelection(cursor);
            return true;
        }
    };

    private View.OnTouchListener mConfirmPasswordVisibleTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final boolean isOutsideView = event.getX() < 0 ||
                    event.getX() > v.getWidth() ||
                    event.getY() < 0 ||
                    event.getY() > v.getHeight();

            // change input type will reset cursor position, so we want to save it
            final int cursor = _confirmPasswordText.getSelectionStart();

            if (isOutsideView || MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction())
                _confirmPasswordText.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            else
                _confirmPasswordText.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);

            _confirmPasswordText.setSelection(cursor);
            return true;
        }
    };

    public void signup() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Begin Signup process...");

        if (!validate()) {
            onSignupFailed();
            return;
        }

        _signupButton.setEnabled(false);

        final ProgressDialog signupProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegisterActivity.this,
                R.style.Theme_IAPTheme);
        signupProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        signupProgressDialog.setMessage("Creating Account...");
        signupProgressDialog.show();

        String name = _nameText.getText().toString();
        String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
        String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();
        String confirmPassword = _confirmPasswordText.getText().toString();

        // TODO: Implement your own signup logic here.

        Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    Log.i("tagconvertstr", "["+response+"]");
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                    if (success) {
                        onSignupSuccess();
                    } else {
                        onSignupFailed();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, email, password, responseListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
        queue.add(registerRequest);

        /*new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        // On complete call either onSignupSuccess or onSignupFailed
                        // depending on success
                        onSignupSuccess();
                        // onSignupFailed();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }, 3000);*/
    }

    public void onSignupSuccess() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Signup Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        _signupButton.setEnabled(true);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
        finish();
    }

    public void onSignupFailed() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Signup Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        _signupButton.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public boolean validate() {
        boolean valid = true;

        Drawable errorIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.eye);
        errorIcon.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100));


        String name = _nameText.getText().toString();
        String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
        String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();
        String confirmPassword = _confirmPasswordText.getText().toString();

        //Trainer Name validation
        if (name.isEmpty() || name.length() < 3) {
            _nameWrapper.setError("enter at least 3 characters");
            _nameWrapper.setErrorEnabled(true);
            valid = false;
        } else {
            _nameWrapper.setError(null);
        }

        //E-Mail validation
        if (email.isEmpty() || !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            _emailText.setError("enter a valid email address");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            _emailText.setError(null);
        }

        //Password validation
        if (password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 4 || password.length() > 10) {
            _passwordText.setError("between 4 and 20 alphanumeric characters");
            valid = false;
        }else {
            _passwordText.setError(null);
        }

        //Confirm Password validation
        if (password.equals(confirmPassword)){
            _confirmPasswordText.setError(null);
        }else {
            _confirmPasswordText.setError("passwords do not match");
            valid = false;
        }

        return valid;
    }
}
```

activity_register.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android.support.design="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/black">

    <!-- Start of Grid Layout -->
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="56dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Logo Icon at the top of the app -->
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2" />

        <!--  Name Text Field -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/nameWrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2">
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/input_name"
                android:theme="@style/MyEditTextTheme"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:hint="Trainer Name (Gamer Tag)" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Email Text Field -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_email"
                android:theme="@style/MyEditTextTheme"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLength="60"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="E-Mail Address" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Password Text Field -->

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="false"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_password"
                android:theme="@style/MyEditTextTheme"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLength="20"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="Password" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Confirm Password Text Field -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="false"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_confirmPassword"
                android:theme="@style/MyEditTextTheme"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLength="20"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="Confirm Password"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Signup Button -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Create Account"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="6"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <!-- Link to Login Activity -->
        <TextView android:id="@+id/link_login"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="Already a member? Login"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16dip"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="7"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <!-- Password Toggle Icon for Password field -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_login_password_visibility"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/eye"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <!-- Password Toggle Icon for Confirm Password field -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_login_confirm_password_visibility"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/eye"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

strings.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:app="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <string name="title_activity_maps">Map</string>
    <!--CODE FOR BUTTON OVERLAY-->
    <string name="Popular"></string>
    <string name="AZ"></string>
    <string name="Category"></string>
    <string name="NearBy"></string>
    <color name="bg_color">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="black">#222222</color>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
    <style name="MyEditTextTheme">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `styles.xml` file, you can create a custom style which uses `@android:style/TextAppearance`

```
<style name="error_appearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red_500</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

And use it in your TextInputLayout widget:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/emailInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance">
```

**Alternatively**, you can modify your theme to change `textColorError`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/control_normal</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/control_activated</item>
    <item name="textColorError">@color/error</item>
    <!-- other styles... -->
</style>
```

and use in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <!-- ... -->

</application>
```

Comment: OMG OMG OMG IT worked!! Thank you soooo much! I had no idea it would be something soo simple! ANSWER ACCEPTED!!!!